# Is it possible to play vs bots on FICS?

Tags: online-chess, cheating

I was playing a 15 min game vs some 2300 guy. He doesn't take any time to think about his next move, not even a second, not even against a c4 opening. When i offered him to play, he accepted immediately, instantly.

He blunders or should I say, he plays slow moves, but he's strong, so no obvious blunders.

Is it possible that bots play on FICS servers? Like you run a bot client, connect it to the server and that's it? since there's no CAPTCHA or anything to make sure that you're a human? And since you can connect to FICS in so many ways?

Comment: Could you find the game in http://ficsgames.org/ and post a link here?

Comment: @JiK c4, and i will try to find it tonight

Comment: What's your rating? For someone rated below 2000, a 2300 might very well look like a computer.

Comment: @JiK removed that part

Comment: removed the parts that you dont like, as for my rating, i don't play on fics so my rating there about 1300, real life i can beat 1900 - 2000, but i don't know my real rating, i'm not a member of any chess club, i'll join one next winter, as i said, he wasn't hard to play against, but the fact that he play instantly after i play my move, instantly like he doesn't even think made me wonder  and it's not a blitz game, i was winning, but my phone battery was like 3% so i attacked and blundered just so i can finish the game before the battery dies :D

Comment: Related: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/how-would-you-determine-that-the-player-is-cheating-in-online-chess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: There are computer accounts in FICS, with handles ending in (C). Also guests may be computers. There might be computers also behind other players, but that's against the rules of FICS. Engines can be connected to FICS using [icsDrone](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icsdrone/), [XBoard/WinBoard](http://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/FAQ.html) with Zippy, or similar tools.

Answer (score -1):

There are some computer accounts that are on the site, so if you see one ending in (C), abort the game or resign. Another website is chess.com, which is really good.